# Опять GDI, опять утечка

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, утечка-памяти, gdi

Вот, код, в ходе которого происходит утечки памяти. **Это происходит, когда изменяю размер окна**

Изначально `ClearSurface` и `ResizeSurface` были одной функцией, я имею в виду, что освобождение памяти происходило в `ResizeSurface`, так что суть не меняется. Утечка происходит **только** во время изменения размеров окна через `WM_NCHITTES`. Когда изменение размеров окна прекращается, то прекращается и утечка.

```
void render(HWND id);

map<HWND, int>main_map;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

class Card
{
public:

bool live;
HWND hwnd;
HDC hdc,hdcc;
HBITMAP bm;
HGDIOBJ bm_old;

bool pause_render;
bool render_stoped;

thread *render_thread;

void Create(int id, wchar_t *caption, int x, int y, int cx, int cy)
{
    ...

    WNDCLASS cl = {};
    cl.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    cl.hInstance = chin;
    cl.lpszClassName = L"class";

    RegisterClass(&cl);

    hwnd = CreateWindow(L"class", caption, WS_POPUP|WS_VISIBLE, x, y, cx, cy, 0, 0, chin, 0);

    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    hdcc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    bm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, cx, cy);

    bm_old=SelectObject(hdcc, bm);

    main_map[hwnd] = id;

    render_thread=new thread(render, hwnd);
    render_thread->detach();

    pause_render = false;
    render_stoped = false;
}

void Delete()
{
    live = false;
    delete render_thread;
}

void ClearSurface()
{
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    SelectObject(hdcc, bm_old);

    DeleteObject(bm);
    DeleteDC(hdcc);
}

void ResizeSurface()
{
    while (!render_stoped)
    { }
    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    hdcc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    bm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, cx, cy);

    bm_old = SelectObject(hdcc, bm);

    pause_render = false;
    render_stoped = true;
}
};

map<int, Card*>card2;

void render(HWND id)
{
for (; card2[main_map[id]]->live;)
{
    Card *card = card2[main_map[id]];

    if (!card->pause_render)
    {
        HDC hdc = card->hdcc;

        Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, card->cx, card->cy);

        TextOut(hdc, 10, 10, card->caption, wcslen(card->caption));

        BitBlt(card->hdc, 0, 0, card->cx, card->cy, card->hdcc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    }
    else
        card->render_stoped = true;
}
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
RECT r;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
switch (message)
{
case WM_NCHITTEST:
    if (LOWORD(lp) > r.right - 5)
    {
        card2[main_map[hwnd]]->pause_render = true;
        while (!card2[main_map[hwnd]]->render_stoped)
        { }
        card2[main_map[hwnd]]->ClearSurface();

        return HTRIGHT;
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:

    break;
case WM_SIZE:
    card2[main_map[hwnd]]->pause_render = true;
    card2[main_map[hwnd]]->cx = r.right;
    card2[main_map[hwnd]]->cy = r.bottom;
    card2[main_map[hwnd]]->ResizeSurface();
    break;
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    wcscpy(card2[main_map[hwnd]]->caption, L"asd");
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wp, lp);
}
return 0;
}

int main()
{
HideConsole();

card2[0] = new Card();

card2[0]->Create(0, L"WORK", 0, 0, 500, 500);

MSG msg;

while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
{
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
}


return 0;
}
```

Как показывает `GdiView`, не удаляются битмапы и hdc. В чём проблема?

Comment: А где освобождение ресурсов в WM_SIZE?

Comment: @Croessmah, `WM_SIZE` у меня вызывается только после `WM_NCHITTEST`. Но, даже если в `ResizeSurface` впихнуть освобождение ресурсов, утечка всё равно происходит. Я же об этом написал в посте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете поток и обращаетесь к общим ресурсам безо всякой синхронизации. Соответственно тут вылезает неопределенное поведение. Используйте mutex или atomic механизмы для синхронизации, напишите RAII врапперы для GDI ресурсов. Я не могу привести источник, но использование GDI ресурсов в потоке, отличном от создавшего их, может быть чревато, так что не факт, что такой фоновый рендерер вообще жизнеспособен (ну или ресурсы для него надо выделять в том же потоке). Кроме того, необходимо корректно обрабатывать `WM_PAINT` хотябы вызвав `ValidateRect`.

Comment: То есть мне из рендера, нужно обращаться к членам класса синхронно? А можно пример кода как с мьютексами, заблокировать доступ к членам класса на время когда они используются в рендере?(но они же там всё время используются-_-)

Comment: При чём, мне важно, чтобы `HBITMAP bm HDC hdc HDC hdcc` реинциализировались только при изменении размеров окна, а не при каждой итерации в `render`

Comment: @АртурКлочко Вот поглядите [пример для `condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: и, подождите а разве у меня не реализована защита от одновременного доступа к ресурсам? Типо `while(!render_stoped)` ну и всё такое?

Comment: я просто в многопоточности пока не очень

Comment: `while(!render_stoped)` - как раз случай неопределенного поведения при обращении к ресурсам из разных потоков. Хотя этот кусок легко подправить заменив `bool render_stoped;` на `::std::atomic<bool> render_stoped;`.

Comment: блин, предложение запихнуть все `HDC, HBITMAP`ы в поток, в котором с ними идёт работа решило проблему, спасибо) Но мне, наверное надо учить мат часть